# A basic doubt on topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a topological vector space and a balanced neighbouhood of $0$ in it. Assume that it is not bounded. Is it true that it is the whole space ? why ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general. An example would be a locally convex space defined by a family of seminorms $p_n(\cdot)$. Then in general $\{x \ | \ p_1(x) < 1\}$ is open, balanced but not bounded since say $p_2(\cdot)$ is not bounded on it. Clearly, it is not the whole space.  A concrete example is $X = C^{\infty}[0,1]$ with  the seminorms $p_n(f) = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} f^{(n)}(t)$.